# Reusable styled components (pseudo element) with logic

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I've written some shared style to be used across different components, how can I change the value of `left` or `width` based a passed value or boolean logic so the values can be more dynamic?

And if possible, I don't want it passed as a prop in the actual component `<bar left="20" />`, but rather just within the declared styles.

```
const shared = css`
  ::after {
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    ${(props) => props.beta && 
    `
      top: 0;
    `
  }
`

const foo = styled.div`
  ${shared}
`

const bar = styled.div`
  ${shared}

  ${child} {
     ${shared}
  }
`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a funtion instead:

```
const getShared = (props) => css`
  ::after {
    content: '';
    left: ${props.left || '0'};
    width: ${props.width || '100%'};
    ${(otherProps) => otherProps.beta && 
    `
      top: 0;
    `
  }
`

const foo = styled.div`
  ${(props) => getShared(props)}
`

const bar = styled.div`
  ${(props) => getShared(props)}

  ${child} {
    ${(props) => getShared(props)}
  }
`
```

if you want to simply override the shared css here is a simple exemple:

```
<div>
      {/* this is a div that uses shared css */}
      <div css={shared}>this is shared css</div>

      {/* this is a div that uses shared css in his styling*/}
      <FirstContainer>container extends shared css</FirstContainer>

      {/* this is a div that uses shared css in his styling but overrides border color using a prop*/}
      <SecondContainer borderColor="red">container overrriding the shared css</SecondContainer>
 </div>
```

and here is the styling:

```
// this is the shared css
export const shared = css`
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px green;
    margin: 40px;
`

// div using the shared css
export const FirstContainer = styled.div`
    ${shared}
`

// div using the shared css but overriding border color
// props contains all the properties passed to the SecondContainer component (like left in bar component)
export const SecondContainer = styled.div`
    ${shared}

    border-color: ${(props) => props.borderColor}
`
```

here is the result :

[image]

Comment: Hi @free-bug-coding
Thanks for your suggestion, I understand the function, but don't quite understand the usage of it, can you be more explicit with the example of say passing 'left' prop or 'otherProps' in the styled components?

Comment: i've added another exemple with comments to explain how can we share a css and use it elsewhere